# Flask : changing location of 'migrations' folder

Tags: python, flask, migration

I have my Flask project hierarchy a

```
project
├── controllers
└── models
    └── schema.py
```

When I run `python schema.py db init`, a `migrations` folder is added under `project` instead of under `models`. I have a `__init__.py` under all 3 folders (not showing here for brevity). I want the `migrations` folder generated under `models`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 31):

Well.. Like Oluwafemi said, you can pass the -d (--directory) flag to your manager script in the cli command

```
python schema.py db init --directory models/migrations
```

The problem with this solution is that you will have to specify the migration path each time you will enter a db command, otherwise you will get the following error:

```
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Path doesn't exist: 'migrations'.  Please use the 'init' command to create a new scripts folder.
```

A better way to config your migration path is by passing the `directory` argument to the `Migrate` object in your manage.py (or in your case, the 'schema.py').

For example:

```
import os
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from .application import app, db


MIGRATION_DIR = os.path.join('models', 'migrations')


migrate = Migrate(app, db, directory=MIGRATION_DIR)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Besides, I suggest you move all the command interface functionality from 'schema.py' to a diffrent python script in your application root path (like, 'manager.py') and create the migrations folder next to your models and not inside it.
The models folder should not contains anything else than the Data Model Objects!

Hope it was helpful..

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the directory option to the init command. This can be the path to the migrations directory. It is set to migrations by default.

```
python schema.py db init --directory models/migrations
```

### Reference:

- API Reference Section https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 4):

Or you can update the location of scripts location in `alembic.ini`

```
# path to migration scripts
script_location = alembic
```

Comment: Only if one uses Alembic. I don't see that OP is doing that.